# Загрузка стиля после выполнения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеются 2 функции для удаления и восстановления музыкального файла

```
function nodelmusic(id) {
        $.post("путь к пхп обработчику",
            function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);  
                 $('#message'+data.id).html('<div class="audio-container"><audio class="mejs-player" src="путь к музыкальному файлу/'+data.file+'" controls="controls"></audio></div>{if $group.id_user == $user.id}<br/><div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-right"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="nodelmusic('+data.id+');" class="btn btn-sm hover-blue style4">удалить</a></div>{/if}<br/><br/><br/>');   
$.getScript("путь к js плагину для стилизации плеера"); 


}
        );
    } 

function delmusic(id) {
        $.post("путь к пхп обработчику",
            function (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);               
                  $('#message'+id).html('<div class="audio-container">Музыкальный файл удален! <span class="right"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="nodelmusic('+data.id+');" class="btn btn-sm hover-blue text-right style4">восстановить</a></span></div>');  
}
        );
    }
```

Проблема в том, что плеер отображается стандартный, не стилизованный стилем.

Comment: При удалении вы используете переменную id, `$('#message'+id)`. При создании, совсем другую переменную, `$('#message'+data.id)`. Так и должно быть?

Comment: в пхп обработчике я отсылаю этот id

$ans = array('id'=>$id, 'file'=>$row['file']);
echo json_encode($ans);

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно после создания плейера его повторно инициализировать:

```
function nodelmusic(id) {
    $.post("путь к пхп обработчику",
        function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);  
            $('#message'+data.id).html('<div class="audio-container"><audio class="mejs-player" src="путь к музыкальному файлу/'+data.file+' controls="controls"></audio></div>{if $group.id_user == $user.id}<br/><div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-right"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="nodelmusic('+data.id+');" class="btn btn-sm hover-blue style4">удалить</a></div>{/if}<br/><br/><br/>');                      
            $('audio.mejs-player').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */); 
        }
    );
}
```

При вызове `$('audio.mejs-player').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);` передайте в `options` те параметры, которыми вы изначально инициализируете плейер.

Answer (score 0):

Тоесть у Вас в dom вываливается голый HTML ? а обработчик , listener событий у Вас под это дело предусмотрен ? после выполнения запроса видимо нужно заного инициализировать плэер .

```
function nodelmusic(id) {
    $.post("путь к пхп обработчику",
        function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);  
             $('#message'+data.id).html('<div class="audio-container"><audio class="mejs-player" src="путь к музыкальному файлу/'+data.file+' controls="controls"></audio></div>{if $group.id_user == $user.id}<br/><div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-right"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="nodelmusic('+data.id+');" class="btn btn-sm hover-blue style4">удалить</a></div>{/if}<br/><br/><br/>');  
             //дальше инициализация плэера , что то типа этого
             $('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);    
          }
    );
}
```

Также можете реализовать пост обработку всех ajax : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

Comment: Вываливается такой http://joxi.ru/5mdQdO3tW0DG21

А вообще вот такой http://joxi.ru/82359aKCL3PNrO

Comment: Повторная инициализация не помогла.

Comment: Дайте адрес страницы где это все происходит

Comment: Вам это ничего не даст т.к. там нужна авторизация под админом.